Windows data drive is not opening in Kubuntu dual boot
I'm just getting started with Linux, and decided to dual boot Kubuntu 24.04 with my Windows 11 laptop. I am entirely unable to access any data on my D Drive via Kubuntu, while Windows is working perfectly fine. There don't seem to be any other issues with Kubuntu either.
In Dolphin I can work with the Kubuntu partition just fine, but the D drive (where all my data is stored) is not visible. The Windows system files are in C drive which I am not trying to touch at all. I know I should mount the partition into Kubuntu, but the instructions I found just say that it will be there on the left pane of the file manager (Dolphin) which is not the case for me.
In Dolphin, under the devices heading on the left pane, are two Basic data partitions which I assume are the C and D drives, but they are not opening. I get a window asking for a password which I don't know where to find. I tried entering my user's password, but that didn't work.
Some things I tried:

Disabling Hibernate and Fast Startup in Windows
chkdsk in Windows

I have a 1TB SSD running Windows 11
When I run lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL it's showing two drives with FSTYPE as BitLocker and no mount point. Is that the issue? I have Windows Home which doesn't have Bitlocker, so why is it showing this?
If I check filetype in Windows, the D drive shows NTFS.

Have you tried entering your user's password? I don't use graphical file managers, but I assume that it is prompting for your password because it needs authentication to mount the drive. Also, please add the output of the commands you mention to your post. Don't describe the output, just paste it in and use the {} button to format it as code. The lsblk output can be useful.

@terdon yes, i did try using the user password. It didn't work. And I will keep in mind the tip about the output for next time. Thank you!

Turns out that what I have isn't BitLocker proper, but Device Encryption, which isn't there in older windows laptops. It can be disabled pretty easily from: Settings > Privacy and Security > Device Encryption.
This also decrypts the drive, resolving the issue!

According to this Microsoft Community post, Bitlocker is available and enabled by default starting from Windows 11 24H2, even for the Home Edition. I have observed the same on a recent laptop.
You might consider creating a second non-encrypted ExFAT or NTFS partition using the windows drive partitioning tool in the "Computer Management" console (not sure if that is available on Home) or the command-line program diskpart. However, you would have to shrink the original partition and file system first.

I don't have the disk space to create another partition where I can copy paste the entirety of the encrypted partition (as I need to be able to edit almost all my data files from both OS's) Is disabling Bitlocker an option? None of the data on it is anything sensitive (I'm a student and it's all my classwork and projects and such) but I also don't want to delete any of it accidentally

@WordWiz I'm not sure if you can disable BitLocker on Windows 11 Home. But superuser.com is probably a better place to ask that. Alternatively you could install an ext2/ext4 filesystem driver in Windows and store all your files on the Linux partition. I had one a few years ago in Windows 7 or 10, but I forgot the name.

I just figured out that what's on my laptop isn't BitLocker but Device Encryption which can be disabled. It's a very new feature introduced only on some windows 11 systems, and I've disabled it now and the issue has been resolved. Thanks for your help!
